# sequelize hasOne how to access relationship?

Tags: sequelize.js

How to access hasOne relationship, it return undefined. I follow documentation. i think, it right already. Its hard to find tutorial to discuss relationship step by step. I see documentation use get in model. like getTag.

app

```
const media = await Media.findOne();
console.log(media.Tag);
```

media model

```
const Tag = require('./tag');
Media.init({
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.BIGINT.UNSIGNED,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        unique: true
    },
    type_id: {
        type: DataTypes.TINYINT.UNSIGNED,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
            model: 'types',
            key: 'id'
        }
}, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Media',
    tableName: 'media',
    engine: 'MYISAM',
    charset: 'utf8mb4',
    collate: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    timestamps: false 
});

Media.hasOne(Tag, {
    as: 'Tag',
    foreignKey: 'type_id'
});
```

tag model

```
Tag.init({
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.MEDIUMINT.UNSIGNED,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        unique: true
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
}, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Tag',
    tableName: 'tags',
    engine: 'MYISAM',
    charset: 'utf8mb4',
    collate: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    timestamps: false 
});
```

Comment: [doc](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAll) by include in findall/one. you  have to include your relation model

Answer (score 0):

You need to [use the `include` property](https://sequelize.org/v3/docs/querying/#relations-associations) in your query to let Sequelize know that you want to fetch data from the relationship. Because relationship hierarchies can be quite extensive it wouldn't be efficient to load them all every time, so you nee to tell Sequelize what you *do* want to load. You can further optimize by using the `attributes` property to only fetch the fields that you need (by default it returns all).

```js
const media = await Media.findOne({
  include: {
    model: Tag,
  },
  where: 
    // ... your criteria
  },
});

console.log(media.Tag);
```